# How to calculate p-value for a survey question with three categorical answers options?

Tags: probability, p-value

I conducted a survey of N=88 students.

I asked a question:
'What type of goal setting do you prefer?'
A: online
B: paper-based
C: no preference

Responses
A: 58
B: 9
C: 21

I will display this result in descriptive statistics, but I want to check for the probability this result in favour of online goal setting came about by chance. For this I believe I need to know the p-value.

What test should I use?
(Someone suggested a answer that suggested a chi-squared test. Is this a good fit?)